# Retrieve content type columns values in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type, document-library

I have a document library content type with multiple columns in Sharepoint2010. I would like to retrieve the values in the column by using the following code but fails.

```
            objCurrentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
            objList = objCurrentWeb.Lists["MyNewLists"];

            foreach (SPListItem objListItem in objList.Items)

            {
                   id = (objListItem["ApplicationId"]).toString();

            }
```

How do I retrieve the values in my content type columns correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It can fail in two cases:
1) There is no such a field "ApplicationId". Ensure you use field internal name
2) (objListItem["ApplicationId"]) is null, so it fails with NullReferenceException on casting to string.